# Modeling a Wire Protocol that allows to send objects over HTTP like application layer protocol

Tags: java, web-services, rpc, corba, peer-wire-protocol

Following is kind of system (a small prototype) I need to build.

"Build a Simple Middleware System. That allows dynamically adding a service into the system and allows accessing the service from a client program. System will include simple utilities to build the server skel and client stub is to be built. To be written in Java; Server side using servlet API to be deployed in Tomcat. On client side, only use the basic socket API and no other libraries used. All processing should be done using basic language constructs. Define a OOPs enabled wire protocol, based on which the system is to be implemented. Should support defining object structure definitions."

Important design decision I need to take is :
"How should I design wire protocol that enables sending of objects and not only premitive data types, I mean what it should include ?"

I found CORBA(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), as good reference. If anyone can explain how it marshalls parameters and in which format it sends data (an example) would do the job.

Thanks.

Comment: OOPs : Object Oriented Programming
Skel : Skeleton

Answer (score 0):

Protocol on the wire is **GIOP** but for a long time already GIOP with TCP/IP transport is used almost everywhere. GIOP with TCP/IP transport is **IIOP**. There's also a secure version with SSL, **SSLIOP**.

[General Inter-ORB Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Inter-ORB_Protocol)

Answer (score -1):

Information about the CORBA wire protocol is part of the [CORBA standard](http://www.omg.org/spec/CORBA/Current). The CORBA wire protocol has a lot of features and capabilities, making a full implementation will be a huge amount of work.

Comment: The question was __If anyone can explain how it marshalls parameters and in which format it sends data (an example) would do the job.__

Comment: How CORBA marshals data is part of the GIOP protocol. It is a binary protocol.